# regex on nested object key to filter list python

Tags: python

I have an array of objects like below:

```py
my_objects = [
    {"id": 1, "labels": {"abc": "123"}},
    {"id": 2, "labels": {"prefix-abc": "123"}},  
    {"id": 3, "labels": {"prefix-abc": "123"}},  
    {"id": 4, "labels": {"xyz-abc": "123"}},  
]
```

I want to be able to filter down to objects that don't have a key in labels that match `prefix-`.

What I'd end up with is:

```py
filtered = [
    {"id": 1, "labels": {"abc": "123"}}, 
    {"id": 4, "labels": {"xyz-abc": "123"}},  
]
```

At the moment I have a working solution but not sure if its the most efficient:

```py
for thing in my_objects:
    labels = thing.get("labels", {})
    for key in labels.keys():
        if "prefix-" in key:
             # handle
```

Comment: If you're looking for code review, there's a separate site: [codereview.se]

Comment: What isn't efficient about this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well that's the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
filtered = [obj for obj in my_objects
            if not any(lab.startswith('prefix-') for lab in obj['labels'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list` comprehensions are more efficient both computationally and in terms of coding space and time than a `for` loop. So another possible solution:

```
import re
my_objects = [
    {"id": 1, "labels": {"abc": "123"}},
    {"id": 2, "labels": {"prefix-abc": "123"}},  
    {"id": 3, "labels": {"prefix-abc": "123"}},  
    {"id": 4, "labels": {"xyz-abc": "123"}},  
]


filtered = [item for item in my_objects for key in item["labels"].keys() if not re.search(r'^prefix-', key)]
print (filtered)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'labels': {'abc': '123'}}, {'id': 4, 'labels': {'xyz-abc': '123'}}]
```